# Xamarin forms : Event Handler with correct signature not found in Type ,

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

After updating to xamarin forms 4.4 we are facing this issue, Updated from xamarin forms forms 3.0 to 4.4 , Any suggestion?

Comment: I guess it is a Picker selection changed event, Since, I too faced this issue while upgrading from 3.0 to 3.4. But more information on which control or event will be an eye opener.

Comment: Based on Tapped Events as we are using TappedEventArgs ,
Void SomeMethod(object Sender , TappedEventArgs)
{
}
Getting Error as "EventHandler "SomeMethod" with correct signature not found",Though Changed TappedEventArgs to System.EventArgs this issue exists.

Comment: @Nikhileshwar how did you Fixed this issue?

Comment: There was a third party tool with PickerEventArgs but Xamarin also introduced PickerEventArgs. This was the reason of my fail. Specifying the correct using for the event solved the issue. Adding code to your Question will help others to answer.

Comment: Where ever you have `TappedEventArgs` in your events you should replace them with basic `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

@FreakyAli 's [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966040/xamarin-forms-event-handler-with-correct-signature-not-found-in-type/66462576#comment106049823_59966040): "Where ever you have `TappedEventArgs` in your events you should replace them with basic `EventArgs`"
worked for me!

I didn't have `TappedEventArgs` in my eventhandler's parameters but rather I was using `ItemTappedEventArgs` but nonetheless this is the fix.

Finally this was the solution that worked for me!